# share more information on var/object properties when on hover for the developer (JS/REACT/TS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a a complex theme object, everything is typed in typescript.

I have an object, lets say:

that's much larger and complex then this:

```
const themeObj = { 
  colors: {
    red1: "#asd123",
    //... etc
  },
  sizes: {
    size1: "10px",
    size2: "11px",
    size3: "14px",
  }
}
```

the ts works fine, in which I can use the theme object and it will show me on hover:

`fontSize: theme.sizes.size3; //can auto complete, and shows me all sizes`

except the main issue I have with this is it only show that the size (i.e. size3) is a `string`

like so:
`(property) size3: string`

It would be extremely valuable if I could add more information to this hover, such as the *actual* value of the string (14px). I could use this sort of detailed feature in multiple places. I have a very difficult time googling this as well.

Is this IDE dependant? I use vscode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you're using TypeScript, you can simply change the `themeObj` to be typed `as const`, and then its values won't be widened to `string`.

[image]

Comment: why does that work? It's so strange that even though it's const, I have to typescript as const in order to behave similarly?

Comment: A JavaScript `const` does not mean immutable. `const arr = [2]; arr.push(3);` or `const obj = { foo: 'foo' }; obj.foo = bar;` But `as const` is TypeScript syntax that indicates everything is readonly (recursively).

Answer (score 0):

try this one:
fontSize: {theme.sizes.size3};

it may work